# Can I separate GRUB and Ubuntu into different disk?

Tags: grub2

I don't want to mess up windows update, bootmbr, and GRUB. So I am planning to install GRUB on my sdcard, and install Ubuntu on my main disk which has Windows 10 installed in a separate partition. Is this possible? Recommended?

Comment: no its not possible if your windows is UEFI installation..while installing Ubuntu.. grub will automatically sits in the EFI partition that is already available for windows..

Comment: If system is older and not UEFI, probably you cannot boot from sdcard anyway. Only a few newer systems allow boot from sdcards.

Answer (score 0):

I will not recommend you to install GRUB on the SD Card. You can configure it easily using the steps given below. However, first, follow the steps to dual-boot your system properly:

1. Boot into `Windows` OS and right-click on the **Start Menu >> Command Line (Admin)** to enter into the Windows command-line interface.
2. Once you are in the command prompt, type `diskmgmt.msc` on the promt to enter into Disk Management utility. From here, right click on C: partition and select **Shrink Volume** in order to resize the partition.
3. Enter a value to shrink your partition. Select **Shrink** to resize the partition to that specific size. We will use this new unallocated space to install Ubuntu.

Do **create a bootable USB** device using either Rufus or Universal USB Installer before you begin with the next section.

Once you have a bootable media follow the link to [dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/).

**Note:** While installation, choose **Install alongside Windows boot manager** and follow every step with caution else you might mess your hard disk permanently.

Also, creating a **Swap partition** is recommended. Having a Swap partition will not affect your working on Ubuntu or on Windows either.

Once you have installed the Ubuntu on your system, the next step would be to **include GRUB on your boot**. To do so, follow the below steps:

- Boot into Windows OS again
- Combine <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> keys together and type `cmd` to enter into your system command prompt.
- Once you are in the command prompt window, type `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` on the prompt and hit the Enter key

**P.S.** You do not require admin rights to execute the above command.

As soon as the command gets executed, reboot your system and then you will always find options to pick either `Ubuntu` or `Windows` as your preferred OS.